# .htaccess redirect if domain = x.example.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a site on a subdomain:

```
x.example.com
```

I put it on a subdomain because it's running on a separate server from the main site.

Using proxy for apache, I have now moved the site to `example.com/x/` I want to make a 301 redirect from the subdomain like this:

```
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/x/
```

but I don't know how to make sure that it does not result in a redirect loop, as the page i'm redirecting to contains the same htaccess-file (as it's a proxy of the old file)

this is what I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^x.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://staging.example.se/x/ [R=301,L,NE]
```

this is my full .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zenqa.herokuapp.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://staging.zenconomy.se/faq/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a backreference, you need a `$1` to get the original request and pass it along to the redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^x.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://staging.example.se/x/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: @KristofferNolgren there must be another rule or something that is causing a redirect, because this rule by itself won't loop unless `x.example.com` is the same as `staging.example.se` (as in the same text, not server)

Comment: Nope, that's not it, they are on different domains. I commented out those two lines and the loop doesn't happen, i can visit both sites without either redirecting to the other. I'm going to look into a RewriteCond that looks at {THE_REQUEST} now.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren Look for anything that redirects to `x.example.com`

Comment: I added my full .htaccess now. I also search my entire code for zenqa,  where the redirect points to, this is the only place that mentions it, apart from the name of a database.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren does `index.php` redirect (for instance, when it sees a request that it doesn't know how to serve)? At any rate, the redirect rule needs to be the first one, otherwise you'll redirect  stuff rewritten by previous rules